# Google indexed my site through a subdomain, how to fix?

Tags: nginx, seo

So I recently switched to nginx but I didn't specify my site_name in nginx.conf, which I've learned is interpreted as a wildcard domain, meaning you can access the site through any subdomain. I had a subdomain DNS 'A' record set up pointing to my site's ip. Somehow google picked up on the subdomain and indexed my entire site's content through the subdomain and now my traffic plummeting. It's down from 4k uniques / day to 1.2k / day. Ouch!

I've specified my site name, and any traffic not coming through www.mydomain gets 301 redirected to www.mydomain. What else can I do to reverse this catastrophe?

I've considered conical links to my content, but I'm hesitant to introduce too many changes at once. I submitted my sitemap to google over a year ago but I haven't updated it since. I do not have a robots.txt file for the site. Is it possible to reverse the damage done?

My site has quality, unique content, and I'm not aggressive with seo, I rarely make changes and have it dialed in to correctly reflect what the site offers.

Comment: You are doing the right thing. HTTP 301 is just what Google recommends in these situations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: This looks like a question for our sister site [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 5):

The 301 redirect that you are doing is the correct way to recover.  The canonical tag that you are considering and 301 redirects can't be used at the same time.  The canonical tag is only for pages that *can't* be redirected.

Recovery should be in a week to a month.  If it is longer than that, it is likely that something else has happened.

Comment: +1 But I wouldn't say that Canonical tags are for non-redirect pages only. They should be on every page where the page had a definite canonical URL.

Comment: A redirect is not a page, as such it is not possible to put a canonical tag on a redirect.   Well, technically there is a page for browsers that don't support redirects.  However all browsers and crawlers now support redirects and that page is completely ignored by search engines.

Comment: I see what you're saying now, and agree. I was thinking something else.

Answer (score 0):

As a belated followup for anyone else experiencing this issue, it took my site about two weeks to fully recover, and there was no permanent damage done to my SEO ranking. Once the site was fully recovered I introduced conical links to all pages to help google identify out of place pages in the event of another such mishap.

Comment: FYI you should be able to use the same StackExchange account on both sites to add a comment to your own question.